# many to many relationship of social network (database)

Tags: mysql, database, facebook

I know technically mysql doesn't support many to many. We should create a bridge table. But in my case I still confused about that.

how 2 tables (or more?) look like when many users can have many friends? think of it like social network app. I want to store users' friend when they connect using fb API. How to connect 2 table below?

```
user
=====
id
name

friend
=====
id
name
```

say jason's friend is jordan, and jordan's friends will definitely be jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a User table as you wrote:

```
user
=====
id
name
```

Then you create a relationship table like this:

```
relationship
=====
from_user_id
to_user_id
```

For example

```
user
=====
1,Jordan
2,Jason
3,Jack
4,Joel

relationship
=====
1,2
1,3
```

indicates that Jordan is both friends with Jason and Jack.

Comment: 2 tables only? I don't get it.

Comment: Why not, it's pretty simple. You have a user table, and store the relationships between users in the relationships table.

Comment: @noob: You should accept this answer, because you are not likely to get any other :-) This is the way to store the relationship you describe in an rdbms.

Comment: Facebook does it in the same way: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/connection/